# How to play stereo stream as stereo on Windows 10

Tags: windows, stereo

I stream **stereo** FLAC from Ubuntu 22.04 with command:

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -i "remote.monitor" -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -f s16le -ac 2 "udp://192.168.1.99:18181"
```

and play this **stereo** stream correctly on macOS with this command:

```
ffplay -nodisp -acodec -ac 2 pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -f s24le -i udp://192.168.1.100:18181?listen=1
```

But if I try to play this stereo strem (with the same command) on Windows 10 ffmpge says:

> "Failed to set value '2' for option 'ac': Option not found"  and plays mono

Would you help me please how to convince ffmpge to play that stream as stereo on Windows 10.